# about game of craps homework

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, random

this is the first time for my asking a question here.
im new to java and i hava a problem with the loop in this code 
i dont know where to break the loop.

thank you for helping me :)
[this image is from the book regarding this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmWfk.jpg)

```
import java.util.*;


     public class GameOfCraps {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rn = new Random();
    int counterw = 0;
    int counterl = 0;
    int countsum = counterl + counterw;
    int points = 0;

    do {
        int rndice1 = rn.nextInt(5) + 1; // 1 to 6
        int rndice2 = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;// 1 to 6
        int sum = rndice1 + rndice2;// sum of dice random

        if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
            // System.out.println("you lose");
            counterl++;
        }

        else if (sum == 7 || sum == 11) {
            // System.out.println("you won");
            counterw++;

        }

        else {
            do {
                boolean xc = false;
                points = sum;
                int rndice3 = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;
                int rndice4 = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;

                if (rndice3 + rndice4 == points) {
                    // System.out.println("you won");
                    counterw++;
                    xc = true;
                    //break;
                }

                if (xc == false)
                    counterl++;

            } while (points != 7);

        }

    } while (countsum <= 10000);
    System.out.println(counterw);
    System.out.println(counterl);
    System.out.println("probability of winning the game: "+(double)(counterw)/(counterw+counterl));

}
```

}

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: what is the actual issue here ? what is the expected outcome and what is the current one ? seems to me you are simply not understanding how the do{]while() works ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in 'second stage' game logic, the game keeps going on after a win and you're incrementing the loss counter after every roll when really it should only be a loss if a 7 is rolled first, and then that game ends. You probably want something more like this:

```
    else {
        while (true) {
            int rndice3 = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;
            int rndice4 = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;

            if (rndice3 + rndice4 == sum) {
                // System.out.println("you won");
                counterw++;
                break;
            }

            if (rndice3 + rndice4 == 7) {
                counterl++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i fixed the code by changing the loop from do{} while {}  to for(){}

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you can just use the `boolean xc` to exit the loop instead of using the point statement (given that the player won i assume the loop is not supposed to run aagin)

now the do{}while() loop works like this

the code in the do is always run ATLEAST 1 time, then the while statement at the end is checked, if the statement is still true it is run again, untill the statement is false, thus what you want here is the exit requirement (given the player won ... just use that ?)

**example**

```
do {
    xc = false;
    if(points == condition){
        xc = true;
    }
    // some code
} while(!xc)
```